# Browser error ssl_error_rx_record_too_long (Firefox) and ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR (Chrome)

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, apache2.4

Can't find the solution to SSL errors with apache2.4.  On my localhost which is Ubuntu LAMP stack it seemed to just stop working a few days ago.. http://example.com works but not https://example.com

Firefox gives me `ssl_error_rx_record_too_long` and Chrome gives me `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`.

I've generated new certificates, and set them to the right domain, but it still fails.

> <VirtualHost _default_:443>
>
> ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
>        ServerName example.dev
>        ServerAlias www.example.dev
>        DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com
>
> ```
>  SSLEngine On
>  SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
>  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key
>
>  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
>  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
>
>  Include /etc/apache2/rules.conf
> ```
>
> </VirtualHost>

It's strange, and a bit frustrating, thank you for the help.

Edit: 
I looked at access.log and I get these errors:

> 127.0.0.1 - - [31/Jul/2014:23:07:47 -0700] "\x16\x03" 400 0 "-" "-"
>      127.0.0.1 - - [31/Jul/2014:23:07:51 -0700] "\x16\x03\x01" 400 0 "-" "-"
>      127.0.0.1 - - [31/Jul/2014:23:07:51 -0700] "\x16\x03\x01" 400 0 "-" "-"
>      127.0.0.1 - - [31/Jul/2014:23:07:51 -0700] "\x16\x03\x01" 400 0 "-" "-" 
>      127.0.0.1 - - [31/Jul/2014:23:07:51 -0700] "\x16\x03\x01" 400 0 "-" "-" 
>      127.0.0.1 - - [31/Jul/2014:23:07:51 -0700] "\x16\x03" 400 0 "-" "-"

Comment: "\x16\x03\x01" is the start of a SSL/TLS handshake. This means, that the browser is attempting to speak HTTPS (HTTP inside SSL), but the server does not expect HTTPS on this port, only plain HTTP (without SSL). Please check your error.log of the server for information about configuration errors in the SSL part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the help, I finally got it right by changing *default*:443 to example.dev:443.